# Populate data from Table in Text Field in VBA

Tags: vba, recordset

I need help populating data from a Recordset into a set of Caption or Text fields, whichever. I have no idea how to proceed. My last try led to disaster.

**Edit** To clarify, here's the query STRING that will go into text boxes in a given Form:

```
"SELECT FROM tbclientes2012 WHERE ccliv = mmyID"
```

Only I don't have a clue on how to do it properly.

Comment: Might help to drop a hint as to which application you're working in.  Also, if you have tried some code, show what didn't work.

Comment: Thank, Tim. You'll understand I'm almost new to this kind of language.

Comment: "My last try led to disaster." What did you try and what kind of disaster resulted?

Comment: It sounds to me as if you are making life difficult for yourself. If you are using MS Access, it will happily build a form based on a query, however, from what you say, it sounds like you have a set of data that you wish to present as a single line. This is probably not a good idea, so it would be as well to show some data and add a few lines on the problem you wish to solve. In addition, there are ways round presenting data as a single line that I would imagine are easier than the methods you seem to be trying.

Comment: I almost think the same, it shouldn't be as complicated but, due to my inexperience it seems impossible, I tried this: 
  `CurrentDb.Execute "SELECT * from tbclientes2012 WHERE UserID = ret"
  Dim mmydao As DAO.Database
  Dim mmydrst As DAO.Recordset
  Dim mmySQL As String
        cpnnombre1.Text = mmydrst.Rows(0)("nnombre1").ToString` and the error is something like "Object was expected."

Comment: That seems to be a peculiar mixture of .net and VBA. Please say what the end result should be and where you are working - MS Access, Excel, VB.Net ...?

Comment: Thanks, Remou. The first thing I want to do is display the text from a field in a Caption or Label using ADO in VB for Access.

Comment: You are using a DAO recordset, not ADO `Dim mmydrst As DAO.Recordset` You are only giving your immediate needs, not explaining the real world problem you wish to solve.

Comment: oh, the goal is to show the name, address, phone of my customers after an ID is provided by them. I know it's a really simple task but can't make my head up to it.

Answer (score 0):

I am posting this reply, but I do not think it is the answer to anything. It assumes that cpnnombre1  is a textbox, not a label. I do not understand where the labels and captions part of the question is coming from. It sounds like a really bad idea to put data in labels.

```
Dim mmydao As DAO.Database 
Dim mmydrst As DAO.Recordset 
Dim mmySQL As String 

Set mmydao = CurrentDb
mmySQL = "SELECT * from tbclientes2012 WHERE UserID = ret"
Set mmydrst = mmydao.OpenRecordset(mmySQL)
Me.cpnnombre1 = mmydrst!nnombre1
```

Depending on the real-world requirements, there could be several other better solutions.

Comment: I am new to VB world and developing an application which has to identify a person using their fingerprint, and i have to autopopulat the textboxes from the database depending upon who has logged in (the returned fingerprint ID from a macro). That is once the userid has been gotten then autopopulating the textbox fields i.e. family name, address, birthday, etc.
Your post looks similar to what i need, except it gives me an "object expected" error on `DAO.Datebase` can you pl. explain the procedure in detail, or perhaps give some sample code to understand it.

Comment: I had an error in the line `Set mmydao`, which I have now corrected. The above is sample code and based on your post.